# How to add a temporary option to a list and display elements based on users responses in Python

Tags: python, list

I have this `list` in `python` which can have `n` elements. Now what I am trying to do is show `4` elements from this `list` at a time with an added option 'next' to show next set of 4 elements. So if my list is something like this:

```
['room 11','room 22','room 33','room 44','room 55','room 65','room 77']
```

then display it to users like this:

```
1. Room Number : room 11
2. Room Number : room 22
3. Room Number : room 33
4. Room Number : room 44
5. Next
```

if user selects `1`(user selects the number corresponding to the room in the list) then print `Room selected: room 11` or if user selects `2` then print `Room selected: room 22`. If user selects `5` then show next set of 4 elements from the list(if less then 4 left than just show whats left).

I wrote this code which is only partial as I am having difficulty in implementing this functionality completely:

```
room_list_num = 0
room_list_slot = 0
def room_try():

    room_list = ['room 11','room 22','room 33','room 44','room 55','room 66','room 77','room 88','room 99','room 110','room 111','room 112']
    inner_list_str = ["%d. Room number: %s" % (i, x)
                      for i, x in enumerate(room_list, 1)]
    global room_list_slot
    while room_list_slot < len(room_list):
        room_list_num = input('Following are the available rooms. Please select the corresponding number of the room you want: \n {}'.format( '\n '.join(inner_list_str[room_list_slot:(room_list_slot+4)])))
        room_list_slot += 4

    print('Room selected: '+ str(room_list[room_list_num]))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    room_try()
```

The difficulty I am having in is to how to add the temporary value 'Next' with each set of 4 elements to display and then move into the list based on users response?

Answer (score 2):

This will help you

```
room_list_num = 0
room_list_slot = 0
def room_try():

    room_list = ['room 11','room 22','room 33','room 44','room 55','room 66','room 77','room 88','room 99','room 110','room 111','room 112']
    inner_list_str = ["%d. Room number: %s" % ((i%4)+1, x)
                      for i, x in enumerate(room_list, 0)]
    global room_list_slot
    counter = 0
    while counter*4 < len(room_list):
        room_list_num = int(input('Following are the available rooms. Please select the corresponding number of the room you want: \n {}'.format( '\n '.join(inner_list_str[room_list_slot:(room_list_slot+4)]) + ['\n 5. Next\n','\n'][room_list_slot+4>=len(room_list)])))
        room_list_slot += 4
        if room_list_num == 5:
            counter += 1
            continue
        break

    print('Room selected: '+ str(room_list[counter*4+room_list_num-1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    room_try()
```

Comment: this executes correct until the last set. It shows `next` as an option there too while there is no next set of elements available. So it should not show `next` when already displaying last set as it will throw error if user selects `next` at that time

Comment: Yes that fixes the issue. I also made a fix by adding another if condition inside while loop to check if its the last set of elements. But yours is much short.

Comment: Another issue is that suppose there are only 9 elements in the list so last set will have only 1 element. But the number option in-front of `next` will still show `5` when it should show `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def room_try():
    room_list_num = 0
    room_list_slot = 0
    room_list = ['room 11', 'room 22', 'room 33', 'room 44', 'room 55', 'room 66', 'room 77', 'room 88', 'room 99', 'room 110', 'room 111', 'room 112']
    inner_list_str = ["%d. Room number: %s" % (i, x)
                      for i, x in enumerate(room_list, 1)]
    while room_list_slot < len(room_list):
        print('Following are the available rooms. Please select the corresponding number of the room you want: \n {}'.format(
            '\n '.join(inner_list_str[room_list_slot:(room_list_slot + 4)])))
        room_list_num = int(input(" {}. Next\n".format(room_list_slot + 5)))
        if (room_list_slot + 5 != room_list_num):
            print('Room selected: ' + str(room_list[room_list_num - 1]))
            return
        else:
            room_list_slot += 4
    print("You haven't choose any room.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    room_try()
```

Comment: when I select `5` then it should show next 4 rooms but it just ends with printing `Room selected: room 55`.

Comment: You are a liar).
Here is a output)
Following are the available rooms. Please select the corresponding number of the room you want:
 1. Room number: room 11
 2. Room number: room 22
 3. Room number: room 33
 4. Room number: room 44
 5 Next.
5
Following are the available rooms. Please select the corresponding number of the room you want:
 5. Room number: room 55
 6. Room number: room 66
 7. Room number: room 77
 8. Room number: room 88
 9 Next.

Comment: Why would I lie? First of all I get error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'` at line `print('Room selected: ' + str(room_list[room_list_num - 1]))`. Then I enclose `room_list_num` in `int()`. Then when I enter 5 to view next 4 elements it just enter room 55

Comment: What version of python do you use?

Comment: I have python 3.6

Comment: somehow `room_list_slot + 5 != room_list_num` is turning out to be true when I select `5` the first time even though it shouldn't as both are equal(5 and 5)

Comment: For me it was a surprise, but in python2.7 this code works well. Maybe input function cast int values to int. I don't know why).

UPD. input(*args, **kwargs) == eval(raw_input(*args, **kwargs)). So, no magic(